# Overload resolution for template operators in namespaces

Tags: c++, namespaces, operator-overloading, overload-resolution

I ran into a bit of trouble with template operator overloads when entering namespaces. Consider addition of arrays:

```
// overloads.hpp
#include <array>

namespace mylib {

template <size_t N>
using DoubleArray = std::array<double,N>;

template <size_t N>
DoubleArray<N> operator+( const DoubleArray<N>& lhs, const DoubleArray<N>& rhs ) {return DoubleArray<N>();}

}
```

Testing this in `namespace mylib` works as intended.

```
// test.cpp
#include "overloads.hpp"

namespace mylib {

void test()
{
    DoubleArray<3> a({1.0,0.0,0.0});
    DoubleArray<3> b({0.0,1.0,0.0});
    DoubleArray<3> c(a+b);                        // <-- ok
}

}
```

Now suppose that I have a `Complex` class in namespace `mylib::mysublib` that has its own `operator+` and a constructor from `DoubleArray` (this constructor has to be explicit to prevent implicit conversion):

```
// nested.cpp
#include "overloads.hpp"

namespace mylib {
    namespace mysublib {

        struct Complex
        {
            Complex() {};
            explicit Complex( const DoubleArray<2>& components );

            DoubleArray<2> _components;
        };

        Complex operator+(const Complex& rhs, const Complex& lhs) {return Complex();}



        void testNested()
        {
            DoubleArray<2> a({1.0,0.0});
            DoubleArray<2> b({0.0,1.0});
            DoubleArray<2> c(a+b);                        // <-- no match for ‘operator+’
            DoubleArray<2> d( mylib::operator+(a,b) );    // <-- ok
        }

    }
}
```

Error message:

```
error: no match for ‘operator+’ (operand types are ‘mylib::DoubleArray<2> {aka std::array<double, 2>}’ and ‘mylib::DoubleArray<2> {aka std::array<double, 2>}’)
     DoubleArray<2> c(a+b);                        // <-- no match for ‘operator+’
```

Why can't the overloaded operator be found when called from the nested namespace? The whole point of overloading (in this example) would be a clean syntax. Any ideas on how to get this working, or if it's even possible?

Comment: You might want to add the [language-lawyer] tag. ADL lookup https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl makes my head hurt

Comment: Please include your error message in the post. Besides, `operator+` is missing its definition. I cannot see any error after adding the function definition of `operator+`.

Comment: @Maverobot Your're right, it did compile. Then the issue gets a bit more complicated, I've updated my question:
I introduced a class in the nested namespace which has its own overload and that breaks the entire thing.

Comment: You want the `DoubleArray<N>` overload to get called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `operator+` of `Complex` can be declared as `friend` function in `Complex`, which does not pollute the global namespace. Your example should compile after the following change.

```cpp
struct Complex {
  Complex(){};
  explicit Complex(const DoubleArray<2>& components);

  DoubleArray<2> _components;

  friend Complex operator+(const Complex& rhs, const Complex& lhs) { return Complex(); }
};
```

According to [C++ standard working draft N4140](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4140/over),

> When two or more different declarations are specified for a single name in the **same** scope, that name is said to be overloaded.

In your case, the two `operator+` functions are declared in different namespace and thus are not qualified for overload resolution.

When compiler finds the first match `Complex operator+(const Complex& rhs, const Complex& lhs)`, `DoubleArray` cannot be implicitly converted to `Complex`. Therefore, you got the `no match for ‘operator+’` error.

Comment: That's it, thanks.
I still don't understand what's going on though. I would have thought that ADL would be able to make the distinction between `Complex` arguments and `DoubleArray` arguments. I have several other overloads for operator+ and I never ran into this issue before. Any hints on what I should read up on to clear this up?

Comment: @KelemenMáté Updated my answer with some more information.

Answer (score 1):

Replace your third code by

```
namespace mylib {
    namespace mysublib {


        struct Complex
        {
            Complex() {};
            explicit Complex( const DoubleArray<2>& components );

            DoubleArray<2> _components;
        };

        //Complex operator+(const Complex& rhs, const Complex& lhs) {return Complex();}



        void testNested()
        {
            DoubleArray<2> a({1.0,0.0});
            DoubleArray<2> b({0.0,1.0});
            DoubleArray<2> c(a+b);                        // <-- no match for ‘operator+’
            DoubleArray<2> d( mylib::operator+(a,b) );    // <-- ok
        }

    }
}
```

, then It compiles.

The definition `Complex operator+(const Complex& rhs, const Complex& lhs) {return Complex();}` hides the intented operator

Comment: I was the downvoter, and now upvoted it. I'm sorry for the inconvenience. I was in the wrong impression that the other operator would be found by ADL (probably because a comment mentioned ADL), but of course that's not the case.

Comment: @anonymous Right, but then `operator+` wouldn't work for `Complex`.
@Johannes I don't get it, why isn't that the case? What makes ADL fail here?

Comment: The solution for that is to declare both functions as `friend`, then define them globally